# Completely stop Terraform generate local state file

Tags: security, terraform

After switch the backend to GCS, I still notice that the state file is generated every time I run apply locally.
According to document: " When using remote state, state is only ever held in memory when used by Terraform. It may be encrypted at rest, but this depends on the specific remote state backend."

is there a way to completely stop generating a local copy of state file and make local apply really that “state is only ever held in memory”??

```
Terraform v1.2.9
google = {
    source  = "hashicorp/google"
    version = "4.15.0"
}
```

thank you

Comment: State will only ever be local or remote. When you switched your backend and done an `init` again you will have had to migrate or reconfigure your backend. have you checked your remote backend to see if the state file is there? have you checked the timestamp on the state file you say is created locally?

Comment: After the switch, I can see on GCS the the state file be created and updated every time, but the local state file still is generated, every time I delete it, it will be re-created again once run terraform apply.

Comment: And your actually seeing the `terraform.tfstate` file and not just the `.terraform.lock.hcl` or something else. You cannot have more than one backend as stated in the docs `A configuration can only provide one backend block.`

Comment: 100% sure, it is the terraform.tfstate file.

Comment: well, this time it is fine, although it has the terraform.tfstate locally, but the file doesn't have full context anymore.
The state file only has something like below:
```
"backend": {
        "type": "gcs",
        "config": {
            "access_token": null,
            "bucket": "ecs-mops-microsite-tf-state",
            "credentials": null,
            "encryption_key": null,
            "impersonate_service_account": null,
            "impersonate_service_account_delegates": null,
            "prefix": "terraform/state"
        },
        "hash": 1850705515
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be closed.
After remove the original terraform.tfstate, although a new file with same name will still be generated, it doesn't have all the information anymore, it only has the backend informaiton